Android pcsc sertificate with private key
I need to get full x509 certificate from smart card in psam slot on android. I got apdu commands working with devices sdk.
On windows this certificate appears in personal store when smart card is inserted and smart card pin is used to unlock it.

Extract x509 der with only public key from smart card by apdu, there is no apdu command in smart card docs for full certificate extraction

Use cn from above certificate to locate full certificate in personal store


How do i get this certificate on android?
I tried looking through all android key stores and various apdu commands that failed.

Smart cards are quite unlikely to support export of the private key. The concept of a smart card is, that it takes care of the private key operations on its own, so the super-sensitive key export is not needed. (Apart from that, ISO 7816 family describes no standardized command for it.)
So even if your specific card may provide the functionality, I don't expect anybody being able to answer this without MUCH more details.
